# Is there any fault in my android manifest file?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am currently working on a xamarin project. Only I'm encountering the error that my Android won't run due to an error in the manifest file. I've never encountered this error myself. Can someone help me with this or tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.fooddev">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
    <application android:label="FoodDev.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application android:label=" GettingStarted.Android">
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
              android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
              android:exported="false"
              android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                       android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I guess that you can always delete a line, and try again. At least to know where the error is

Answer (score 0):

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
              android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
              android:exported="false"
              android:grantUriPermissions="true">
          
  // Here is Your Error You are missing File provider_path in your resources
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                       android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />

</provider>
```

[image: Like This]